# Hooks countdown timer does not show zeros

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, countdown

Countdown timer does not show zeros values.
When seconds or minutes approaching zero, timer delete span, where showing value.
If timer time 7 minutes 00 seconds he shows 7, but i need minutes 07 seconds 00

Time used React hooks.

Code

```
function calculateTimeLeft() {


const year = new Date().getFullYear();
  const difference = +new Date(`${year}-10-1`) - +new Date();
  let timeLeft = {};

  if (difference > 0) {
    timeLeft = {
      days: Math.floor(difference / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)),
      hours: Math.floor((difference / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24),
      minutes: Math.floor((difference / 1000 / 60) % 60),
      seconds: Math.floor((difference / 1000) % 60)
    };
  }

  return timeLeft;
}
export default function App() {
  const [timeLeft, setTimeLeft] = React.useState(calculateTimeLeft());

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const id = setTimeout(() => {
      setTimeLeft(calculateTimeLeft());
    }, 1000);

    return () => {
      clearTimeout(id);
    };
  });

  const timerComponents = Object.keys(timeLeft).map(interval => {
    if (!timeLeft[interval]) {
      return;
    }

    return (
      <span>
        {timeLeft[interval]} {interval}{" "}
      </span>
    );
  });

  return (
    <div>
      {timerComponents.length ? timerComponents : <span>Time's up!</span>}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This check prevent the rendering of the `interval` for every falsy value, which means that `0` won't be rendered as well:

```
if (!timeLeft[interval]) {
  return;
}
```

You should check if the value is `undefined` to skip rendering, although it's redundant your case. An empty object would produce an empty array of keys, which means that the `forEach` callback won't be invoked.

```
if (timeLeft[interval] === undefined) {
  return;
}
```

Demo:

```js
function calculateTimeLeft() {
  const year = new Date().getFullYear();
  const difference = +new Date(`${year}-10-1`) - +new Date();
  let timeLeft = {};

  if (difference > 0) {
    timeLeft = {
      days: Math.floor(difference / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)),
      hours: Math.floor((difference / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24),
      minutes: Math.floor((difference / 1000 / 60) % 60),
      seconds: Math.floor((difference / 1000) % 60)
    };
  }

  return timeLeft;
}
function App() {
  const [timeLeft, setTimeLeft] = React.useState(calculateTimeLeft());

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const id = setTimeout(() => {
      setTimeLeft(calculateTimeLeft());
    }, 1000);

    return () => {
      clearTimeout(id);
    };
  });

  const timerComponents = Object.keys(timeLeft).map(interval => {
    if (timeLeft[interval] === undefined) {
      return;
    }

    return (
      <span key={interval}>
        {timeLeft[interval]} {interval}{" "}
      </span>
    );
  });

  return timerComponents;
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  root
);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Another option is to avoid creating all `timerComponents` if `timeLeft` is `null` (instead of setting an empty object):

```js
function calculateTimeLeft() {
  const year = new Date().getFullYear();
  const difference = +new Date(`${year}-10-1`) - +new Date();

  return difference > 0 ?
    {
      days: Math.floor(difference / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)),
      hours: Math.floor((difference / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24),
      minutes: Math.floor((difference / 1000 / 60) % 60),
      seconds: Math.floor((difference / 1000) % 60)
    } : null;
}
function App() {
  const [timeLeft, setTimeLeft] = React.useState(calculateTimeLeft());

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const id = setTimeout(() => {
      setTimeLeft(calculateTimeLeft());
    }, 1000);

    return () => {
      clearTimeout(id);
    };
  });
  
  if(!timeLeft) return null;

  return Object.keys(timeLeft).map(interval => (
    <span key={interval}>
      {timeLeft[interval]} {interval}{" "}
    </span>
  ));
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  root
);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```